# Subtracting two COUNT(*) statements returns correct number but 12,000 rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to subtract them to show that there was a total gain (or loss) of tasks for the last week. the result returns the correct result but 12,000 times.

I have two queries that each return a number, 6 and 4. I want to subtract them to show that there was a total gain (or loss) of tasks for the last week.

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*) FROM db1 WHERE db1.[creation date] >Date()-7)
      -(SELECT Count(*) FROM db1 WHERE db1.[completed date] >Date()-7)
FROM db1
```

When I run this query, it returns the correct number but it repeats the number 12,000 times, once for each record.  I just want a single number returned so I can use it in a text box on a form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT (SUM(IIF(db1.[creation date] > Date() - 7, 1, 0)) -
        SUM(IIF(db1.[completed date] > Date()-7, 1, 0))
       )
FROM db1;
```

You are confusing subqueries and outer queries.  In your version, you have a query on `db1` -- the entire table.  It is not an aggregation query, so every row is returned.  What does the result contain?  It contains the results of the subqueries -- but repeated for each row.  You could add `db1.*` to the `select` to see this.

This version is an aggregation query.  It uses conditional aggregation to get the result.  And, it should be much faster than your version as well.

Comment: but it would still return as many results as there are rows in the db1 table?

Comment: @RokSprogar How so? The records are aggregated by the `sum` function and with no `group by` clause, only one record will ever be returned.

Comment: @RokSprogar . . . Absolutely not.  This is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.  Such queries always return one row.

Comment: I know aggregates return a single result without a group by, but I thought it could happen because both SUMs are wrapped in another (...), which looked like it may result in per-row "sums"...never executed the query, though :)

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest the following as an alternative to conditional aggregation:

```sql
select a.c1 - b.c2
from
(select count(*) as c1 from db1 where db1.[creation date]  > Date()-7) a,
(select count(*) as c2 from db1 where db1.[completed date] > Date()-7) b
```

The above uses a cartesian product (also known as a cross join). This means that, for each record output from the first table, every record is output from the second table (i.e. the total number of records output is the number of records in each table multiplied together).

However, since each subquery in this particular cartesian product will only ever return **one record** (the result of `count(*)` for the given conditions), the final result is sourced from a dataset comprising of 1x1=1 record containing the two values to be subtracted.

Comment: `"will only ever return at most one record"` No, they will both return exactly one record. Even if db1 were completely empty the sub queries would still return one row each with the value 0.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Corrected above, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more optimized (and easier) way of getting that value into the form field is to use a function along the lines of this:

```
=DCount( "*", "db1", "[creation date] >Date()-7" ) - DCount( "*", "db1", "[completed date] >Date()-7" )
```

Though you might have to tweak it a bit (syntactically), it's been years since I've had access installed on this machine. :)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT Count() FROM db1 WHERE db1.[creation date] >Date()-7) -
(SELECT Count() FROM db1 WHERE db1.[completed date] >Date()-7)
)
```

ps: not tested!

Comment: You cannot use an arithmetic operator to "join" two datasets within a `from` clause, this is invalid syntax in MS Access.

Answer (score -1):

You are returning 12,000 rows because your table db1 has 12,000 rows. You need to use a FROM clause with a table that only has one record, create a table equivalent to DUAL in Oracle.

Try this:

```
-- Create DUAL Table
CREATE TABLE DUAL
(
   DUMMY VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO DUAL (DUMMY) VALUES ('X');

--Use Dual Table for your computation
SELECT 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM db1 WHERE db1.[creation date] >Date()-7)
-
(SELECT Count(*) FROM db1 WHERE db1.[completed date] >Date()-7) AS COUNT_DIFF
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: When I do that is give the error "Query input must contain at least one table or query."

Comment: @DanielPhillips Ah! You can only remove the from clause for simple queries like 'SELECT 1' not complex queries like this one. You can use a distinct. I've update the query.

Comment: But the idea to run each subquery 12000 times only to let the DBMS find out later that it can remove 11999 rows is terrible.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner What do you think about this solution?

Comment: This is a good solution. (I actually even suggested to create such single row table, when Salman A's original solution - the exact same query without `FROM DUAL` - failed.)